# Model reference for when dependent variable is a percentage-sequence

Tags: references, model

I am not a statistician, but I do have some experience within the field.

I am currently in need of analysing a data set in which there are a few explanatory variables for each subject, and the dependent variable is a sequence of percentages, where each percentage indicates how large a share of their income the subject has spent on a pre-specified set of categories (food, bills, clothing, etc).

Could I possibly get recommended a list of models/techniques/references that are useful to know when analysing such a data structure? You can be as broad as you like, don't worry about prerequisites either.